# Cron restart in OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: linux, cron, opensuse

In Suse Enterprise 10 & 11 & 12, we can restart the crontab after update via the following command:
/etc/init.d/cron restart

In OpenSuse platform, I could not find it. I thought maybe there is a different way related to the service management tool "systemd". How can cron restart be performed in OpenSuse?

Comment: Try 'systemctl restart cron.service' but OpenSuse doc says /etc/init.d/cron should exists https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Cron

Comment: Yes I also read that documentation about cron daemon. However I installed OpenSuse 13.2 and there is no such a file (/etc/init.d/cron). Meanwhile "systemctl restart cron.service" works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So for OpenSuse 13, the way to go for restarting the cron service is:

```
systemctl restart cron.service
```

Comment: i get `Failed to start cron.service: Unit cron.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`